# Not so much sound related, but an etiquette request...

Tags: discussion, etiquette

Hey folks. I see this happen every once in a while on the site here. A whole string of questions that were asked ages ago suddenly get bumped to the top of the list by the site's coding, burying recent questions that are still active.

My request? If you're one of the people who asked a question that just reappeared, go in and select an "answer" if a good one was provided, or close the question if you no longer care. Naturally, leave it alone if you're still waiting for one (maybe edit the question itself with an update).

Let's keep this site productive and relevant!

**UPDATE:** Well, we seem to be getting nowhere with people policing their own posts. Won't you join me in voting to close those posts that get automatically cycled back to the top? We need 5 votes to actually close a question. You can find the "close" link directly beneath the subject tags.

Comment: Totally agree! One point however, you can't delete a post all by yourself. One needs four votes to delete a post.

Comment: @Arnoud Traa - used the wrong word there. should have said "close," which you can do to your own questions. have made the correction. thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: It seems to me that these kinds of solutions are scratching the surface and the real problem is a lack of users. Users may also be on related sites on SE like Signal Processing. I think generating site interest is in order.

Comment: Also, closing posts like this goes against SE design. It's kind of like... cannibalism.

Comment: @FizzledOut - This request was from when a large group of us were on a site called Social Sound Design...which later merged with SE. We had a long standing problem with people who would ask a question, get a bunch of responses, and never select an "answer." We'd end up with a feed full of questions that were no longer relevant when they got an auto-bump.

Comment: @ShaunFarley Oh. I heard references about SSD and had some suspicions, but I didn't know until now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To further update on this, I have noticed that the site has a process which keeps preventing old posts from closing.  Whenever the "community" refreshes a question, it blows out ALL close flags.  I know because I've flagged some of these posts three times, and each time it come back up to the top, it resets the close count.  Thus, unless we as a community get aggressive in flagging these certain posts (each one requires 5 or more close flags), they'll stay open indefinitely.

Comment: Is closing something that only more senior members can do? I'm here almost every day and I'd love to help out, but I'm not seeing a "close" link...

Comment: According to the FAQ it looks like a user must have 3000+ reputation to have the option to flag a post for closure.


Answer (score 1):

Bump ... hehehe

Answer (score 1):

I feel this needs another bump, I'm still seeing A LOT of the same 10-15 questions repeat for the past year (which have receive thorough answers or aren't directly questions but have received community feedback), because of it either being a drive-by question (user creates account, asks question, never returns/follows up) or they forgot to select an answer.  Personally I'm finding it a tad bit annoying so feel a reminder of Shaun's post is worth refreshing.  What is the suggested close flag reason for neglected/rebounding questions?  "No longer relevant"?

I have a feeling many on here know the 10-15 questions I'm talking about by now ;)

Answer (score 1):

I also find this a bit tedious.  One thing I notice is that often these questions that constantly recirculate have been asked by users with very low reputations.  This leads me to think they have joined SSD, asked their questions, got an answer and then not bothered returning.  If this is that case could we have a system where if a question has been open for over a year and user has not been to SSD in 6 months and has a user reputation of say less then 50(?), then the question is either automatically closed or can be closed by a moderator?

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with you Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

I closed my Mac vs Windows question about whether an OS was significantly more unadapted than the other for using Pro Tools. Says I still need 4 votes to close it though.

If you want it closed, have at it! :) [Pro Tools on Windows vs. Mac: Any difference?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/1731/pro-tools-on-windows-vs-mac-any-difference)

Comment: that's not one of the auto-bump posts, justin. ;) if people feel the desire to continue discussing that one, i say have at it. lol

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should take your own advice and choose an answer. Otherwise it will auto bump again as it did today.

Comment: i see it as a good reminder. ;)